# Change display of WP REST API Date

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm doing a Angular Wordpress theme and displaying the date on posts using {{post.date}} . This displays the date as it is in the WP REST API as 2017-07-17T12:48:51 . I am wanting to display the date as July 7, 2017 .I've tried changing the date in the general settings date format but that did not affect the display of the date.

Comment: post.date is a Javascript date object or string?

Comment: @WasifKhan it's a string - date: "2017-07-17T12:48:51"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use filter like following:

```
{{post.date | date}}
```